# Can't call class's method c#

Tags: c#, methods

I know I'm missing something obvious but for some reason I can't call a method from a class. I have one file named Searches with a SearchGroup method in it. I am attempting to call that method from another file by the following, but it's saying

> 'Searches' does not contain a definition for 'SearchGroup' :

```cs
List<Searches.NameScore> People = Searches.SearchGroup("Test");
```

My `Searches` class looks like:

```cs
public class Searches
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public Searches(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _config = configuration;
        }
        
        public class FirstLoadGroup
        {
            public int IdGroup { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        public class NameScore
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public double Score { get; set; }
        }        
        public async Task<List<NameScore>> SearchGroup(string Input)
        {            
           //processy stuff

            //Querying stuff
            DataAccess data = new DataAccess();
            string sql = "SELECT IdGroup, Name FROM Groups";
            List<FirstLoadGroup> Names = await data.LoadData<FirstLoadGroup, dynamic>(sql, new { }, _config.GetConnectionString("DataDB"));

            //Sorting and Comparing stuff
            return SortedNames;

            //return list of names in order of lowest to highest matching score
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you create an instance of your searches class ?

Comment: Declare these two classes outside the Searches class.

Comment: Is `Searches` in your code an instance variable? I ask because it looks like no (your searches has a capital S implying static access) but you've declared your List as being called People so you seemingly don't stick to c# variable naming conventions

Comment: [C# Guide - Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods#:~:text=Methods%20can%20be%20either%20instance,that%20instance%20and%20its%20data.)

Comment: I don't know what an instance variable is, nor what naming conventions are ._.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up take those classes out of searches (generally you should avoid declaring classes inside other classes):

```
public class Searches
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public Searches(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _config = configuration;
    }
           
    public async Task<List<NameScore>> SearchGroup(string Input)
    {            
       //processy stuff

        //Querying stuff
        DataAccess data = new DataAccess();
        string sql = "SELECT IdGroup, Name FROM Groups";
        List<FirstLoadGroup> Names = await data.LoadData<FirstLoadGroup, dynamic>(sql, new { }, _config.GetConnectionString("DataDB"));

        //Sorting and Comparing stuff
        return SortedNames;

        //return list of names in order of lowest to highest matching score
    }
}

    
    public class FirstLoadGroup
    {
        public int IdGroup { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class NameScore
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Score { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you need to be calling your method like:

```
Searches s = new Searches(some config)
List<NameScore> people = await s.SearchGroup("Test");
```

That said, if you have a property like:

```
public Searches Searches { get; set; }
```

..then Searches.SearchGroup is acceptable, but the fact that C# seems to know what Searches is but not that it has a SearchGroup method would imply that you have two+ classes called Searches and the one it's found for your code's context is not the one with the SearchGroup method. Check your usings and aliases

Comment: ps; naming conventions, broadly speaking - PublicThings, _privateThings, localThings

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately it doesn't fully work, I used the find feature of Visual Studio to look for other classes with the same name but it was the only one. I added an empty constructor to Searches, and currently my error message is on ```s.SearchGroup("Test")``` saying that "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'SimilarPeople.s(the name of the file it's in)" Itellisense is recognizing that SearchOfficer exists now though

Comment: That error is unrelated to this one, and I can't see in the posted code anything that would throw it; that error happens when you try to give a member a default value when declared, that comes from another member - i.e. You've tried to write something like `class Person { int age = 20; string ageString = age.ToString(); ...` - there is no guarantee that age=20 is done first, so you can't reference age when initializing ageString. You need to use a constructor to order these assigns. Adding an empty constructor to Searches might not help; _config is needed by SearchGroup and should not be null

Comment: Opps, SearchOfficer is the same thing as SearchGroup, I just changed the name to make it more general for the question. Thanks for the advice

Comment: (This comment has been reposted with typos fixed)
If Searches must take an IConfiguration then either the thing that constructs a Searches must know of a config instance it can supply, or Searches needs to be constructed by the dependency injector that knows what config to supply, or SearchGroup must be reworked to not be reliant on _config. Not sure what a SearchOfficer is; this is the first time you mentioned it

Comment: Generally I'd advise NOT changing code for a question, because errors can creep in as you edit the code which means we end up diagnosing on code that doesn't represent the real life and giving advice that cannot be pasted in and work

Answer (score 1):

You can only call static methods without any instance of the class. To call SearchGroup method, you either

1. make it a static method

   public static async Task<List> SearchGroup(string Input)
2. or create a instance of the call and then call method on it.

   s = new Searches();
   await s.SearchGroup("Test");

Answer (score 0):

Try using `await`

```
List<Searches.NameScore> People = await Searches.SearchGroup("Test");
```

Comment: I should put in an await, but currently that only adds on another error message because it isn't finding the async SearchGroup method

Comment: if the function is not static you need to initialize class. Searches searches = new Searches(); await searches.SearchGroup("Test");